# Symfony: Override plugin-model in other plugin

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, symfony-plugins

we are building a new website, which will reuse an existing symfony-software used by another website. I'm moving reusable components into a plugin ("app-plugin"), in order to avoid duplicating code and data. The plugin will be configured as svn-external in the websites' svn repositories.

The existing symfony instance contains overridden doctrine classes (models, forms, form-filters) which are originally defined in other plugins (e.g. sfDoctrineGuardPlugin). The overridden classes can be reused by both symfony-instances, therefore I'm going to move them to the "app-plugin". But this causes problems:

If someone, for instance, runs `symfony doctrine:build-forms`, the moved files will be re-created by the task inside lib/form/doctrine and will contain empty class-definitions. The reason is very clear to me: How was symfony supposed to know that the "app-plugin" is already defining those form-classes? The only way would be to autoload all classes before executing the task and checking whether classes are already available.

A workaround would be to exclude those classes in the app-plugin's config/autoload.yml. But is there a better way?

**Edit**

I'm using the term "app-plugin" to avoid confusion between normal plugin (e.g. sfGuard) and our plugin which contains shared components.

---

Before:

[image: dependencies before]

---

After:

[image: dependencies after]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no better way than excluding the original model in the *app-plugin's* config/autoload.yml. Even if you can derive model-classes as shown in the images above you'll get in trouble as soon as you run the build-forms task. I looked through the form-generator's source code which reveals that this isn't possible. Therefore, the only solutions are: avoiding the build-forms task, rewriting the form-generator or, as already stated, using autoload.yml.

Answer (score 2):

What is this "app-plugin" you are talking about ? Normally, all you have to do is leave your overriden classes where they are, and move the code they contain in the parent classes, which are supposed to be in the plugin. And if you want to change the behavior for a particular symfony app, then you may edit these overriden classes.

Comment: I used the term "app-plugin" to avoid confusion between normal plugins (e.g. sfGuardPlugin) and our plugin which contains reusable components for both websites. The overridden sfGuardPlugin models / forms can be reused by both websites as well. I cannot move overriden classes to the sfGuardPlugin which defines the parent classes in this case.

Comment: @fishbone: I think I understand your problem better. If you're not too reluctant to edit the sfGuardPlugin (I know, it is bad pratice), you can disable automatic form and filter generation in the schema.yml file by adding "options:\n
  symfony:\n
    filter: false" on top of it, and inherit the sfplugin files in your app-plugin. You will still have a problem with the model files though.